# how to organize fixture data and access them from tests in C/C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, waf, catch-unit-test

How do I compute the path to data fixtures files in test code, given:

- `test/{main.cpp,one_test.cpp,two_test.cpp}`
- compilation done in `build/`
- `test/fixtures/{conf_1.cfg}`

The problem I'm facing is as follows:

```
/* in test/one_test.cpp */
TEST_CASE( "Config from file", "[config]" ) {
  Config conf;
  REQUIRE( conf.read(??? + "/conf_1.cfg") )
}
```

The solution I found so far is to define a macro at configure time:

```
#define TEST_DIR "/absolute/path/to/test"
```

which is obtained in my `wscript` with

```
def configure(cnf):
    # ...
    cnf.env.TEST_DIR = cnf.path.get_src().abspath()
    cnf.define('TEST_DIR', cnf.env.TEST_DIR)
    cnf.write_config_header('include/config.h')
```

Other attempts included `__FILE__` which expanded to `../test/one_test.cpp`, but I couldn't use it.

Some background: I'm using the [Catch testing framework](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch), with the [waf build tool](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_17/single.html).

Is there is a common practice or pattern, possibly dependent on the testing framework ?

Comment: While it may certainly differ between testing frameworks, a common solution would be to define a macro in the build-framework, and pass it to the sources a e.g. `-DTEST_DIR="\"/som/path/to/test\""`.

Answer (score 1):

We found this hard to solve at compile/build time as refactoring components (and therefore tests) would move code around. We found two possible solutions:

1. Put the data into the test. This is only practical if it's short and humanly readable - strings or an easy hex-dump. You could always put the data into a header file if that would make the test easier to maintain.
2. Specify the location of the data files at the command-line when you run the tests. For this, you may need your own main (See ['Supplying your own main()'](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/own-main.md)